# Hyundai accent 2012 check engine light

Tags: hyundai, cel, accent

my accent 2012 check engine light flashing until car warmed up in the morning, then it's turned off after 2 minutes, I have changed the spark plugs and ignition coils, but still have the issue, also no error recorded when checked the car by ODB scanner. the car is performing well except this warning

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does the car run rough at start, or have any issues other than the light showing?